# Progress indicator during pandas merge (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm merging pandas datasets with millions of rows... how can I get a progress bar so I can get some ides of the processing time?

I only see one available for apply functions.

Comment: try python widgets..

Comment: Obligatory "store your data in a real database and do the operations there".